# Multi-dimensional ArrayPool usage

Tags: arrays, .net, performance, optimization, multidimensional-array

I just found out about the [`System.Buffers.ArrayPool<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1) class

There is a great blog here: https://adamsitnik.com/Array-Pool/ explaining its usage.

However, in my use-case, I have a three dimensional array to rent and release.

1. How do I initialize and rent it?
2. From the documentation, it mentions that it may be oversized. So, with my 3D array situation, does it mean, it MAY oversize on the 3 dimensions?

Should it look like this?

```vb
Dim Double3DArrayPool As ArrayPool(Of Double()()) = ArrayPool(Of Double()()).Shared

' rent a 12x4x20,000 array????
Dim some3DData = Double3DArrayPool.Rent(12 * 4 * 20000)
```